# How do I find the best exchange rate to convert 1 million Swedish krona into Euros?

Tags: foreign-exchange, money-transfer, international-transfer

I have 1 million SEK in a Swedish bank account which I wish to transfer to my bank account in a country using the Euro. How do I transfer this money so as to avail of the best possible exchange rate? I am planning on buying an apartment with the money in question.

Comment: Make a SEPA payment.

Comment: Generically, I think your best bet would be to use some kind of (Swedish) online currency exchange (and *then* making a SEPA transfer). If you let the banks do it for you, the rates will more likely than not be abysmal, and they might put an additional surcharge on top of that. On the other hand, with such a large amount, you could try negotiating for a decent exchange rate. That said, the market exchange rate might fluctuate daily more than the spread in a good online exchange, so it may not be worth the effort.

Comment: Commercial banks deal with this on a daily basis...

Comment: @keshlam That doesn't mean they'll give you a god exchange rate.

Comment: FOREX brokers often advertise they have the "best" rates (lowest bid-ask spread). You might contact one of them and ask if you can "take delivery" of the money instead of just rolling it over.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at Transferwise. They have low fees and often beat the banks. They (broadly speaking) work by finding people who need to convert money the other way round and then just push money around in the respective local currency.

Comment: Other services have better rates once you factor transferwises "hidden" fees

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, but care to mention some that have lower fees for samll amounts (<5000 EUR) ? They might be useful for me

Comment: Usforex and XE trade